# cakephp display image from database

Tags: php, database, cakephp

Since it's not a large number of images that my db will take, i'm uploading them directly to database. However, i'm having problems displaying them, i don't want to download them, i want to see them on the page. I'm trying to display with the following code but it's not working:

function display() of MyFiles Controller:

```
    function display($id)
   {

      $file = $this->MyFile->findById($id);
    $this->set('image',$file['MyFile']['data']);

   }
```

MyFile Model:

```
    <?php 
class MyFile extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'MyFile';

}

?>
```

function add() of MyFilesController

```
function add() {            
    if (!empty($this->data) && 
         is_uploaded_file($this->data['MyFile']['File']['tmp_name'])) {
        $fileData = fread(fopen($this->data['MyFile']['File']['tmp_name'], "r"), 
                                 $this->data['MyFile']['File']['size']);

        $this->request->data['MyFile']['name'] = $this->data['MyFile']['File']['name'];
        $this->request->data['MyFile']['type'] = $this->data['MyFile']['File']['type'];
        $this->request->data['MyFile']['size'] = $this->data['MyFile']['File']['size'];
        $this->request->data['MyFile']['data'] = $fileData;

        $this->MyFile->save($this->request->data);

        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'index'));
    }
}
```

EDIT:

display.ctp of MyFiles View

```
    <?php

echo '<img src="/MyFilesController/display/4" />';
?>
```

Comment: Does your layout have:                                                  <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

Comment: How are you trying to load the image into a browser? data urls? image display script called from a `src="..."`?

Comment: @MarcB could you please be more specific? If i would use scr shouldn't be to a directory folder and not database?

Comment: you did not specify your cake php version. please do so - always.

Comment: `<img src="somescript.php?imageID=xxx">` or `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,....">`? Somehow you've got to get your image from PHP to the browser in a form that the browser recognizes.

Comment: post the contents of `display.ctp`; and you need to set the appropriate headers if you are serving *just* the image.

Comment: @marc version 2.0 of cakebook

Now the icon of the "image missing" appears, but not the image itself.

Comment: @MarcB i updated the img src and the display() method, please take a look.

Comment: @Ross i posted the contens of display.ctp and updated the display() method, please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Saving images in a database is generally not a good idea.

You are far better off (and I assume you have done this for 'security') saving the files in a folder that is not web accessible and using [Media Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html) to render them. This way you can still keep your security checks as you are using a controller to render the image.

Cakes media views are designed for streaming files to the browser and can easily be configured for images.

2.3 has a new [feature](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file) for this

If you are not doing this for security reasons just save your self the problems and put them in `webroot`.

Comment: i was saving them on the database, so i was not saving them in some folder but well, i'm trying change to that way and only use a reference to the url of the image in the database table to later show the images on the browser pages, that's what i'm triyng right now, but having some difficulties

Comment: Use this plugin https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload, it has good docs and works out the box.

Comment: @Ross had already recommend them, and i confess during my research i found that page. Well, i will try and say something later

Comment: i was able to upload the images to the webroot/files/user/photo/..

But now, how can i through the table that was them referenced, show the images on the web page of the application?